# How can I ensure that I get different results for the $trip[0]['image_name'] each time that I loop through the $trips

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using the code below to display images for all available trips. However, it only returns the image for the first trip. I have two different MySQL tables for trips and images and I trying to use the tripId to sources a corresponding 'image_name' from the images table

```
<?php foreach($trips as $trip):         

    $tripId = $trip['id']; 
    $tripImage = array_filter($tripImages, function($array) {
        global $tripId;
        return $array['tripId'] == $tripId;

    });
    
?>

<div class="trip-card">
    <img class="trip-card-image" src="images/<?php echo $tripImage[0]['image_name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $trip['tripname']; ?>">
    <h3 class="trip-title"><?php echo $trip['tripname']; ?></h3>
    <p class="trip-description"><?php echo $trip['description']; ?></p>
</div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What query are you running? How are you running it and fetching the data?

Comment: Why is `$tripId` set as `global`?

Comment: @tadman I set `$tripId` as global, because it returns undefined when I do not

Comment: Slapping `global` on something doesn't fix problems like that, it just makes new ones. The reason it's undefined is because `$trip['id']` is undefined, and as to why that's the case, see my earlier comment.

Comment: @tadman this is the code for the trip images `$sql = "SELECT tripId,image_name FROM trip_images"` and this is for the trips `"SELECT id, tripname, description, id FROM trips ORDER BY created_at";`

Comment: That's the query. See part two: "How are you running it and fetching the data?"

Comment: @tadman I am storing the response from `mysqli_query($con, $sql)` in a `$result` variable, then fetching the `$trips` using `mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`. I also deploy the same approach for images

Comment: Time to check with `var_dump($trip)` what you're getting to be sure you're accessing it correctly.